# How to unscrew from narrow gap?

Tags: screws

On my computer case, I found a screw in this position.
[image: the position of screw]

How can i unscrew it.

Comment: Looking at the photo I see no reason a normal screwdriver won't fit, though it will need to be long enough the handle doesn't hit the case.  Can you upload some better pictures that more clearly show the problem?

Comment: Almost useless picture. It is so unfocused that nothing can be inferred from it. Try again and this time post annotate the picture so we know what you are talking about.

Comment: a in focus photo would be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

### Angled screwdrivers

[image]

Though I've always found them unsatisfactory.

### flexible extension shaft

[image]

If you have room, this may work better

Comment: I can buy them. But i doubt whether even these would work as the gap is to narrow, asyou can see in the pic.

Comment: The angled screwdriver will fit, you just need to be very careful applying force using it.

Comment: Pardon fur asking, are there angled screwdrivers as small as that gap.?

Comment: Have you considered that in asking that question it might be helpful for you to provide measurements of the gap? A better focused photo with a ruler across the gap would have been a good way to do this.